# SPSS Return Highest Variable Name

Tags: syntax, spss

1) I need SPSS to return the variable name of the highest variable in a series of subscales. Basically I have ten subscales with mean scores ranging from 0 to 5, I don't want to know the highest score for each case, but rather which subscale is highest.

When I use this syntax, I just get the score, which doesn't tell me which category it belongs to.

```
COMPUTE Motivation_Highest2 = MAX(Stress_Mgmt, Revitalisation, Enjoyment, Challenge,    SocialRecog, Affiliation, Competition, HealthPress, IllHealth, PosHealth,
WtMgmt, Appearance, StrengthEnd, Nimbleness, MotivationHighest).

VARIABLE LABELS Motivation_Highest2 'Motivation Intensity: Highest Score on any Motivation Subscale'.

EXECUTE.
```

Can I ask SPSS to return the variable name instead of the score?

2) There may be two scores that are both equally high. In this case, I would like SPSS to give me both variable names.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an ok job for a macro to do.

```
DEFINE !MaxVars (OutN = !TOKENS(1)
                /OutV = !CHAREND("/")
                /Var = !CMDEND)
NUMERIC !OutN.
!DO !I !IN (!Var)
  COMPUTE !OutN = MAX(!OutN,!I).
!DOEND
STRING !OutV (!CONCAT("A",!LENGTH(!Var))).
!DO !I !IN (!Var)
  IF !I = !OutN !OutV = LTRIM(CONCAT(RTRIM(!OutV)," ",!QUOTE(!I))).
!DOEND
!ENDDEFINE.
```

And here is an example of using it on a set of data.

```
DATA LIST FREE / X1 X2 X3.
BEGIN DATA
1 2 3
3 2 1
4 4 0
0 4 4
1 1 1
END DATA.
!MaxVars OutN = Max OutV = Vars /Var = X1 X2 X3.
```

If you then run `LIST Max Vars.` it will return in the output:

```
Max Vars 

 3  X3 
 3  X1 
 4  X1 X2 
 4  X2 X3 
 1  X1 X2 X3
```